# How to calculate the shortest path using R when points do not fall in the path?

Tags: r, spatial, shortest-path

I have two point shapefiles, one for investigated points (red points) and one for the point of the town center (pink triangles), and one line shapefiles denoting the roads.

Investigated points, town center and roads

[image]

I want to calculate the length of shortest path from the investigated points to the town center based on the road map. However, as you might see the points are not exactly fall in the roads. I tried to seek the solution using igraph but it might not match the data I have. I am new to R, would you please kindly let me know if there is any packages or solutions that I can use for such data.

Comment: Work through `?optim`.

Comment: You could try one of the packages spatstat.linnet or sfnetworks.

Comment: consider building a check in your script to search for nearest point on line and start from there.